# Issues with 2nd gen iPod touch

Tags: iphone, applications, ipod-touch, wifi, ios-appstore

I have a 2nd gen iPod touch (bought around 3 years back)...Off late, I am facing some issues with it; Date/Time gets reset on a few ocassions even though I charge it regularly (mostly seems to be a battery issue)

But the major issue is with AppStore downloads. Most of the apps just do not download. After I enter my username/password, it shows the icon with Waiting for long time, but the download never starts. I know a few might be bcoz of compatibilty issues, But this happens for almost 90% of my app downloads.

Please let me know if it is time to get a new iPod touch OR if the issue can be rectified with some minor corrections. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you may try to restart it. Hold Power button for that.

Second, if this will not help try restore your iPod.
For this connect it to iTunes, choose Backup from iPod contextual menu and then press Restore. This way you will be able to rectify software problems.

Then you may try [to restore iPod in Recovery mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1808).

If it will not help then it is either network issue or you do try to install iOS4+ only apps.

[More on restore process](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1414).

Comment: Actually, i have already tried resetting the ipod...but that did not help much...

Comment: If you believe it's not a network issue (and you can use Mail, Safari, iTunes store on it) try restoring it in Recovery mode. I've updated original answer with a link.